# Left Join gives no result

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

These are the two tables.

tbl_Invoice

[image: Invoice]

tbl_Payment

[image: Payment]

**What I want is `Pending Invoices` by a particular Client.**

Existing Query is as below:

```
Select * from tbl_Invoice I 
    left join tbl_payment P on I.client_id = P.client_id
    left join tbl_client C on I.client_id = C.client_id
    where I.invoice_Id not in (P.invoice_Id) 
    and I.client_id = 8
```

But it gives blank result becuase the Payment table is blank.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to move condition from `WHERE` to `ON` :

```
Select * from tbl_Invoice I 
left join tbl_payment P on (I.client_id = P.client_id 
 AND p.invoice_id <> I.invoice_Id)
left join tbl_client C on I.client_id = C.client_id

WHERE I.client_id = 5
```

Comment: Nice..!! Can you explain a little bit..??

Comment: `I.invoice_Id not in (P.invoice_Id) ` returns `NULL` if tbl_payment is empty. `NULL` is treated as FALSE in logical statements; so you get empty resultset. In general, when you use `LEFT JOIN` you don't want to put anything `left join`ed into `where` because it turns your `left join` into `inner`. Exception - that's ok and common practice to use `WHERE left_joined_table.primary_key_column IS NULL` to get all records in parent table that don't have details...